# gem install bundler, bundle not working

Tags: centos, gem

So this is a bit weird.  Gem works fine.  When I go to `gem install bundler`, the system outputs the following:

```
  Successfully installed bundler-1.16.2
  1 gem installed
```

When I check to see what gems are installed with `gem list` the bundler shows up:

```
  *** LOCAL GEMS ***

  bigdecimal (1.2.0)
  bundler (1.16.2)
  io-console (0.4.2)
  json (1.7.7)
  psych (2.0.0)
  rdoc (4.0.0)
```

and yet when I go to run `bundle install`, I get the following:

```
  bash: bundle: command not found
```

I have tried restarting the system, I have used `yum erase gem` and then reinstalled it, and I have tried `gem install bundler` again when it didn't work and I am still getting the same error.  I am on CentOS 7.5

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What user are you running the `bundle` command as?  On my CentOS system, `bundler-1.16.2` installed the binary `/usr/local/bin/bundle` which is not in the `root` user's `$PATH` by default.

Comment: I am running as a root user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit behind on CentOS 7.4 but that shouldn't matter here.

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

Here I'm installing `bundler`:

```
$ sudo gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.16.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.2
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.16.2
1 gem installed
```

And it's located here:

```
$ type -f bundler
bundler is /usr/local/bin/bundler

$ sudo bundler -v
Bundler version 1.16.2
```

And here's my `$PATH`:

```
$ sudo echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/root/bin
```

However when I try the `bundle` command it fails for me in `sudo` as well:

```
$ sudo bundle -v
sudo: bundle: command not found

$ sudo type -f bundle
sudo: type: command not found
```

If I do this after logging directly into root it works though:

```
$ type -f bundle
bundle is hashed (/usr/local/bin/bundle)
```

If we do the full path it works as expected:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/bundle -v
Bundler version 1.16.2
```

This would indicate that it's a `$PATH` issue when you're running the commands as different users.

Comment: It guess it was just the issue with sudo.  That is curious...   however thank you so much, I am now on my way